# jquery doesn't recognize an id of html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why the jQuery click event on `#btn` doesn't work.

```
`//this is the script` 
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    alert('2');
  });
});

function appendToPopUp(){
  document.getElementById('popUp').innerHTML='<BUTTON id="btn" onClick="alert(1)">clickerIci</BUTTON>';
}

<!--this is the body-->
<DIV id='popUp'></DIV>
<BUTTON onClick='appendToPopUp()'>display</BUTTON>
```

Comment: It should be `$(document).ready(...`

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems here:

```
$('document').ready(...
```

should be:

```
$(document).ready(...
```

Then you dynamically insert the `btn` button. Since it's not available at `document.ready` the event is not attached to it at all. You'll have to reattach the event inside `appendToPopUp`.

```
function appendToPopUp()
{
  document.getElementById('popUp').innerHTML='<BUTTON id="btn" onClick="alert(1)">clickerIci</BUTTON>';

  $('#btn').click(function(){
    alert('2');
  });
}
```

So, in this case, you actually don't need `$(document).ready()`.

**Edit**

What I'd *actually* do is something like this:

```
<DIV id='popUp'></DIV>
<BUTTON id="display">display</BUTTON>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#display').on('click', function() {
    $('#popUp').html('<BUTTON id="btn">clickerIci</BUTTON>');

    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
      alert('2');
    });
  });
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Dys/1/).

Comment: Or you could delegate event too

Comment: thank youuu Sani now it work , the important is now i understand why , two days of suffring thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with the below HTML...
On page load Jquery doesn't know about #btn so it will not bind the events so we explitcly calling the bindevents function after it is loaded to DOM.

<script>
function bindevents(){
    $('#btn').on("click",function(){
          alert('2');
    });
}
function appendToPopUp()
{
  document.getElementById('popUp').innerHTML='<BUTTON id="btn"   onClick="alert(1)">clickerIci</BUTTON>';
   bindevents();
}
</script>
<DIV id='popUp'></DIV>
<BUTTON onClick='appendToPopUp()'>display</BUTTON>
```